# Replace fragment in another Activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have two FragmentActivitis. I can go from Activity (A) to Activity (B) , and after replacing different fragments, there is a home button in (B) which should go back to the Activity(A)'s first fragment. My code is :

```
btnHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();

                MainActivity.fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                                new firstFragment())
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();


            }
        });
```

Which `fragmentManager` is :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

that is in MainActivity, but I get the error below :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

How can I handle this ?!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it by replacing `commitAllowingStateLoss()` with `commit()`. So it became like this :

```
 MainActivity.fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                                new firstFragment())
                        .addToBackStack(null).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: This isn't a good approach. Better add `onActivityResult()` in your activity A and start activity B with `startActivityForResult`. Then when you return from activity B replace the fragment.